# Tengo un error al querer ejecutar "mongod.exe"

Tags: mongodb, mongod

estoy tratando de crear un bot de discord a base de tutoriales, ya que siempre me intereso el tema de la programación, así que opte por guiarme con tutoriales.
Pero, llegue a la parte en donde un tutorial enseña como instalar MongoDb para incluirlo al bot, todo iba bien, la instalación se hizo correctamente, no hubo ningún error, hasta que necesitaba ejecutar el archivo "mongod.exe", lo hice correctamente tal y como indicaba en el tutorial. Me metí a la cmd y puse "cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin", luego puse "ls", me aparecieron varias opciones y seleccione la de "mongod.exe", hasta ahí todo bien, hasta que me sale un error, ya me he fijado en varías paginas, pero no encontre nada similar. Este es el error que obtengo:

````
λ mongod.exe
2020-12-13T10:01:05.938-0300 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-12-13T10:01:06.805-0300 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-12-13T10:01:06.810-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7656 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-S6IFGBG
2020-12-13T10:01:06.810-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-12-13T10:01:06.810-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.11
2020-12-13T10:01:06.811-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ea38428f0c6742c7c2c7f677e73d79e17a2aab96
2020-12-13T10:01:06.811-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-12-13T10:01:06.811-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-12-13T10:01:06.812-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-12-13T10:01:06.812-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2020-12-13T10:01:06.812-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-12-13T10:01:06.813-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-12-13T10:01:06.815-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-12-13T10:01:06.930-0300 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
2020-12-13T10:01:06.941-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-12-13T10:01:06.944-0300 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2020-12-13T10:01:06.945-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7143M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-12-13T10:01:07.135-0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1607864467:135137][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1607864467:135137][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-12-13T10:01:07.197-0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1607864467:196668][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1607864467:196668][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-12-13T10:01:07.222-0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1607864467:221690][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1607864467:221690][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-12-13T10:01:07.266-0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1607864467:265733][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1607864467:265733][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-12-13T10:01:07.310-0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1607864467:309774][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1607864467:309774][7656:140715651194528], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-12-13T10:01:07.318-0300 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2020-12-13T10:01:07.318-0300 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-12-13T10:01:07.319-0300 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 925
2020-12-13T10:01:07.320-0300 F  -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n```
````

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría instalar de nuevo mongodb y para ejecutar crear un PATH y no tener que ir al directorio raiz para ejecutarlo

[Guia de como añadir PATH en windows](https://java.com/es/download/help/path_es.html)

PATH:

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin

Una vez hecho esto ya solo escribes en la terminal

> mongo

Y se ejecutara normalmente

Comment: ¿Y no serái mejor referenciar la guía de instalación de software del programa que usa el OP? https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/install/